# What is the difference between the two similar sentences?

Tags: past-vs-past-perfect

(1) I brought the book that I {bought} on the previous day.
(2) I brought the book that I {had bought} on the previous day.

I think the two sentences are the same in their meanings.   If not, could you kindly tell me the difference?  Thank you always

Answer (score 1):

> I brought the book that I bought on the previous day.

This sentence is in simple past tense.

> I brought the book that I had bought on the previous day.

This sentence is in past perfect tense. Use this when you have to refer "past of the past".

For example,

> When I was in the office, I realized that I had left sunglasses in the car in the parking lot.

In the above example, we're using past of the past by using had.